# Issues while installing RCurl

Tags: r, libcurl, rcurl, install.packages

I am trying to install `RCurl`. But getting following error while installing:

> checking for curl-config... no
>   Cannot find curl-config
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’

So tried installing `libcurl4-openssl-dev` on my `Redhat 6` server.
But getting

> No package libcurl4-openssl-dev available.

I have already installed `curl` and `libcurl-devel`.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo yum install libcurl-devel`as mentioned on the github page of the package?

Comment: Yes, Package libcurl-devel-7.19.7-46.el6.x86_64 is already installed and latest version

Comment: Also tried `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` as mentioned in http://askubuntu.com/questions/359267/cannot-find-curl-config-in-ubuntu-13-04? This was for Ubuntu, but should also work for Redhat, I think.